# Extract element from pytube array produce error

Tags: python, arrays, pytube

I tried to extract element and assign it to variable from array but it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    itag_start =  element.find(itag)
AttributeError: 'Stream' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This is my code

```
from pytube import YouTube
link = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
array = link.streams.all()
itag = 'itag'
mime_type='mime_type'
res='res'
counter = 0
iv = []
mt = []
re = []
    for element in array :
        itag_start =  element.find(itag)
        if itag_start != -1:
            itag_end = element.find('"', itag_start+len(itag)+2)
            itag_value = element[itag_start+len(itag)+1:itag_end+1]
            iv.insert(counter,itag_value)
        mime_type_start =  element.find(mime_type)
        if mime_type_start != -1:
            mime_type_end = element.find('"', mime_type_start+len(mime_type)+2)
            mime_type_value = element[mime_type_start+len(mime_type)+1:mime_type_end+1]
            mt.insert(counter,mime_type_value)

        res_start =  element.find(res)
        if res_start != -1:
            res_end = element.find('"', res_start+len(res)+2)
            res_value = element[res_start+len(res)+1:res_end+1]
            re.insert(counter,res_value)
         counter = counter + 1
```

However if I replace link.streams.all() directly with the output, the error will gone.

```
[<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2">,
 <Stream: itag="43" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp8.0" acodec="vorbis">,
 <Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2">,
 <Stream: itag="36" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2">,
 <Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2">,
 <Stream: itag="137" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.640028">,
 <Stream: itag="248" mime_type="video/webm" res="1080p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="136" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401f">,
 <Stream: itag="247" mime_type="video/webm" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="135" mime_type="video/mp4" res="480p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e">,
 <Stream: itag="244" mime_type="video/webm" res="480p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="134" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e">,
 <Stream: itag="243" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="133" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d4015">,
 <Stream: itag="242" mime_type="video/webm" res="240p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="160" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d400c">,
 <Stream: itag="278" mime_type="video/webm" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2">,
 <Stream: itag="171" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="128kbps" acodec="vorbis">,
 <Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus">,
 <Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus">,
 <Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus">]
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your line:

```
textitag_start =  element.find(itag)
```

to

```
itag_start =  str(element).find(itag)
```

PyTube's stream list produced by your statement `array = link.streams.all()`  creates  list elements of non-quoted strings. `.find(itag)` must operate on a string, that's why you get the error, the PyTube list elements are not strings.

Using `str(element)` converts the PyTube list element to a string. Be advised that PyTube list elements used in `.download` statement must NOT be in quotes, they must retain their original format as in the stream list.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the type of the streams you're getting

```
video = yt.streams.all()
for i in video:
    print(type(i))
```

the output will be this:

> <class 'pytube.streams.Stream'>

the .find attribute only works for the string class types. Type cast the element with the str.

> itag_start =  str(element).find(itag)

and replace all the element.find with str(element).find